# Export shared mailbox to PST fails with "Unknown Error"

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, outlook-2016

Situation:

- Exchange server 2010
- Outlook 2016

Email account when added to Outlook automatically adds a few shared mailboxes.
I want to backup (create PST) one of these shared mailboxes.
However when exporting the shared mailbox to PST via Outlook it fails with an "Unknown Error." 
[image]

Via Exchange server 2010 itself I've tried the New-MailboxExportRequest (even with -BadItemLimit 9 and -MRSServer ) but the PST created there is smaller compared to the one that Outlook 2016 created till it failed. So I think the New-MailboxExportRequest just stops when it fails, but I have no idea if it is incomplete, successful etc... (I guess incomplete because it is smaller?)

Via C:\Users\wst.WINKING\AppData\Local\Temp\Outlook Logging I used tracerpt foo.etl  to see the log file and this is the result:

```
Files Processed:
    Outlook-20180605T0831020847.etl
Total Buffers Processed 909
Total Events  Processed 375535
Total Events  Lost      0
Start Time              dinsdag 5 juni 2018
End Time                dinsdag 5 juni 2018
Elapsed Time            2777 sec
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Event Count   Event Name           Task            Opcode          Version         Guid                                  |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|          1   EventTrace           0               PartitionInfoExtension 2               {68fdd900-4a3e-11d1-84f4-0000f80464e3}|
|          1   EventTrace           0               Header          0               {68fdd900-4a3e-11d1-84f4-0000f80464e3}|
|          4                        8               0               0               {691e1c12-2693-4d4a-852c-7478657bbe6e}|
|     174885                        1               0               0               {691e1c12-2693-4d4a-852c-7478657bbe6e}|
|      87423                        6               2               0               {691e1c12-2693-4d4a-852c-7478657bbe6e}|
|      87423                        6               1               0               {691e1c12-2693-4d4a-852c-7478657bbe6e}|
|          8                        0               1               0               {691e1c12-2693-4d4a-852c-7478657bbe6e}|
|          9                        0               2               0               {691e1c12-2693-4d4a-852c-7478657bbe6e}|
|        150                        0               0               0               {691e1c12-2693-4d4a-852c-7478657bbe6e}|
|        117                        8               2               0               {284b8d30-4aa6-4a0f-9143-ce2e8e1f10f0}|
|       3872                        8               0               0               {284b8d30-4aa6-4a0f-9143-ce2e8e1f10f0}|
|        121                        8               1               0               {284b8d30-4aa6-4a0f-9143-ce2e8e1f10f0}|
|      21320                        6               0               0               {284b8d30-4aa6-4a0f-9143-ce2e8e1f10f0}|
|          1                        0               0               0               {2adf8e23-0af9-43c9-ba4c-952ee130540d}|
|         56                        1               0               0               {2adf8e23-0af9-43c9-ba4c-952ee130540d}|
|         12                        0               0               0               {aa8fa310-0939-4ce3-b9bb-ae05b2695110}|
|          2                        1               0               0               {11adbd74-7df2-4e8e-802b-b3bcbfd04a78}|
|         83                        13              0               0               {11adbd74-7df2-4e8e-802b-b3bcbfd04a78}|
|         25                        3               0               0               {11adbd74-7df2-4e8e-802b-b3bcbfd04a78}|
|         12                        10              0               0               {11adbd74-7df2-4e8e-802b-b3bcbfd04a78}|
|         10                        6               0               0               {d8d0510d-3f14-4da9-a096-b9c7ad386da0}|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Event Count   Event Name           Event ID        Version         Guid                                  |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|          1   EventTrace           0               0               {68fdd900-4a3e-11d1-84f4-0000f80464e3}|
|          1   EventTrace           0               2               {68fdd900-4a3e-11d1-84f4-0000f80464e3}|
|      87423                        3               0               {691e1c12-2693-4d4a-852c-7478657bbe6e}|
|      87423                        4               0               {691e1c12-2693-4d4a-852c-7478657bbe6e}|
|          2                        194             0               {691e1c12-2693-4d4a-852c-7478657bbe6e}|
|          1                        255             0               {691e1c12-2693-4d4a-852c-7478657bbe6e}|
|      21844                        256             0               {691e1c12-2693-4d4a-852c-7478657bbe6e}|
|      21874                        258             0               {691e1c12-2693-4d4a-852c-7478657bbe6e}|
|      21874                        259             0               {691e1c12-2693-4d4a-852c-7478657bbe6e}|
|      21870                        260             0               {691e1c12-2693-4d4a-852c-7478657bbe6e}|
|          4                        262             0               {691e1c12-2693-4d4a-852c-7478657bbe6e}|
|          4                        264             0               {691e1c12-2693-4d4a-852c-7478657bbe6e}|
|          1                        266             0               {691e1c12-2693-4d4a-852c-7478657bbe6e}|
|          1                        267             0               {691e1c12-2693-4d4a-852c-7478657bbe6e}|
|      21850                        269             0               {691e1c12-2693-4d4a-852c-7478657bbe6e}|
|          9                        271             0               {691e1c12-2693-4d4a-852c-7478657bbe6e}|
|          2                        313             0               {691e1c12-2693-4d4a-852c-7478657bbe6e}|
|          4                        317             0               {691e1c12-2693-4d4a-852c-7478657bbe6e}|
|         10                        327             0               {691e1c12-2693-4d4a-852c-7478657bbe6e}|
|      21844                        373             0               {691e1c12-2693-4d4a-852c-7478657bbe6e}|
|          1                        381             0               {691e1c12-2693-4d4a-852c-7478657bbe6e}|
|      21844                        387             0               {691e1c12-2693-4d4a-852c-7478657bbe6e}|
|      21844                        388             0               {691e1c12-2693-4d4a-852c-7478657bbe6e}|
|          1                        395             0               {691e1c12-2693-4d4a-852c-7478657bbe6e}|
|          1                        6020            0               {691e1c12-2693-4d4a-852c-7478657bbe6e}|
|          2                        6030            0               {691e1c12-2693-4d4a-852c-7478657bbe6e}|
|          2                        6031            0               {691e1c12-2693-4d4a-852c-7478657bbe6e}|
|          1                        21000           0               {691e1c12-2693-4d4a-852c-7478657bbe6e}|
|          1                        21001           0               {691e1c12-2693-4d4a-852c-7478657bbe6e}|
|          1                        21002           0               {691e1c12-2693-4d4a-852c-7478657bbe6e}|
|         40                        21003           0               {691e1c12-2693-4d4a-852c-7478657bbe6e}|
|          1                        21005           0               {691e1c12-2693-4d4a-852c-7478657bbe6e}|
|        105                        21009           0               {691e1c12-2693-4d4a-852c-7478657bbe6e}|
|          8                        21012           0               {691e1c12-2693-4d4a-852c-7478657bbe6e}|
|          9                        21013           0               {691e1c12-2693-4d4a-852c-7478657bbe6e}|
|          1                        21014           0               {691e1c12-2693-4d4a-852c-7478657bbe6e}|
|      21320                        5               0               {284b8d30-4aa6-4a0f-9143-ce2e8e1f10f0}|
|         12                        301             0               {284b8d30-4aa6-4a0f-9143-ce2e8e1f10f0}|
|         13                        302             0               {284b8d30-4aa6-4a0f-9143-ce2e8e1f10f0}|
|         25                        303             0               {284b8d30-4aa6-4a0f-9143-ce2e8e1f10f0}|
|         92                        304             0               {284b8d30-4aa6-4a0f-9143-ce2e8e1f10f0}|
|       3733                        305             0               {284b8d30-4aa6-4a0f-9143-ce2e8e1f10f0}|
|         89                        306             0               {284b8d30-4aa6-4a0f-9143-ce2e8e1f10f0}|
|          1                        307             0               {284b8d30-4aa6-4a0f-9143-ce2e8e1f10f0}|
|         15                        309             0               {284b8d30-4aa6-4a0f-9143-ce2e8e1f10f0}|
|         16                        310             0               {284b8d30-4aa6-4a0f-9143-ce2e8e1f10f0}|
|         89                        311             0               {284b8d30-4aa6-4a0f-9143-ce2e8e1f10f0}|
|         25                        314             0               {284b8d30-4aa6-4a0f-9143-ce2e8e1f10f0}|
|         56                        800             0               {2adf8e23-0af9-43c9-ba4c-952ee130540d}|
|          1                        2001            0               {2adf8e23-0af9-43c9-ba4c-952ee130540d}|
|          4                        311             0               {aa8fa310-0939-4ce3-b9bb-ae05b2695110}|
|          4                        332             0               {aa8fa310-0939-4ce3-b9bb-ae05b2695110}|
|          4                        345             0               {aa8fa310-0939-4ce3-b9bb-ae05b2695110}|
|          8                        151             0               {11adbd74-7df2-4e8e-802b-b3bcbfd04a78}|
|          1                        163             0               {11adbd74-7df2-4e8e-802b-b3bcbfd04a78}|
|         16                        177             0               {11adbd74-7df2-4e8e-802b-b3bcbfd04a78}|
|         11                        213             0               {11adbd74-7df2-4e8e-802b-b3bcbfd04a78}|
|          1                        216             0               {11adbd74-7df2-4e8e-802b-b3bcbfd04a78}|
|          1                        243             0               {11adbd74-7df2-4e8e-802b-b3bcbfd04a78}|
|          2                        363             0               {11adbd74-7df2-4e8e-802b-b3bcbfd04a78}|
|         22                        615             0               {11adbd74-7df2-4e8e-802b-b3bcbfd04a78}|
|         18                        623             0               {11adbd74-7df2-4e8e-802b-b3bcbfd04a78}|
|         41                        628             0               {11adbd74-7df2-4e8e-802b-b3bcbfd04a78}|
|          1                        635             0               {11adbd74-7df2-4e8e-802b-b3bcbfd04a78}|
|         10                        25338           0               {d8d0510d-3f14-4da9-a096-b9c7ad386da0}|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I can't find any details about these event id's.

When opening the etl with Event Viewer I see that event id 21013 is an Error.
and same with event id 21003 and 21012. These errors occur but I can't find any details about these 3 event id's.

Any idea how to correctly export the complete shared mailbox data to PST? (or to figure out which item is creating the failure?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running "New-MailboxExportRequest" cmdlet, you can run the following command to verify if the the progress of export request is successful :

```
Get-MailboxExportRequestStatistics -Identity UserName\MailboxExport -IncludeReport | Fl
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the mailbox that you have full access permission from Outlook. Then you need to create a new Outlook profile and resync this account in Outlook. Do the mailbox export again to have a try. If the Cached mode doesn't work properly, try Outlook Online mode to do the export.